# XSD - one of 2 attributes is required?

Tags: xsd

Is there a way to specify that one of 2 attributes is required in XSD?

for example, I have a definition like this:

```
<xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
<xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
```

I want to be able to define that at least one of these is required. Is that possible?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, I don't think you can do that with attributes. You could wrap two `<xs:element>` into a `<xs:choice>` - but for attributes, there's no equivalent construct, I'm afraid.

Comment: This doesn't work with mutliple elements with the same name... i.e. I want three possible combinations of an element of a certain name, and making a choice of the three complex types with the same names fails :(

Answer (score 30):

XSD 1.1 will let you do this using asserts.

```
<xsd:element name="remove">
    <xsd:complexType>                        
        <xsd:attribute name="ref" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="uri" use="optional"/>
        <xsd:assert test="(@ref and not(@uri)) or (not(@ref) and @uri)"/>            
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but since it was released in 2012 (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/) , and I'm using .NET 4.0, (released in 2010) it's not supported.  Is it supported in .NET 4.5?  Example class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swxzdhc0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Cannot we do something like `<xsd:assert test="(@ref or @uri)"/>` ?

Comment: I don't believe that the xsl 'or' is exclusive. We want it to be one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 9):

Marc is quite right... You cannot have xs:attribute child elements inside a xs:choice parent element in XSD.

The logic seems to be that if two instances of an element have a mutually exclusive set of attributes then they are logically two different elements.

A workaround for this has been presented by Jeni Tennison [here](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/200107/msg00038.html).

Answer (score 5):

You should look at this pages on W3C wiki: [Simple attribute implication](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Simple_attribute_implication) and [Attribute muttex](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Attribute_mutex)

Answer (score -3):

The example  defines an element named "person" which must contain either a "employee" element or a "member" element.

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="employee" type="employee"/>
      <xs:element name="member" type="member"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: The question is not asking about elements, but attributes.