# Force the XML parser to raise a parse error, if irrelevant tag attributes were to be specified in a tag

Tags: jsf, xml-parsing, tag-handler

I have a basic tag handler for a JSF converter as follows (several things have been omitted for brevity).

```
<tag>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[
            Converts a string representation to 
            <code>java.math.BigDecimal</code> based on attribute values given.
        ]]>
    </description>
    <tag-name>convertBigDecimal</tag-name>
    <converter><converter-id>bigDecimalConverter</converter-id></converter>

    <attribute>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217">ISO 4217 currency code</a> such as INR, USD, GBP, NZD etc.
            ]]>
        </description>
        <name>currency</name>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>

    <attribute>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[
                A boolean value or flag indicating whether to transform 
                this value to percentage or not. The default is false.
            ]]>
        </description>
        <name>percent</name>
        <type>java.lang.Boolean</type>
    </attribute>

    <attribute>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[
                A boolean value or flag indicating whether to use a 
                currency symbol (such as $) or not. The default is true.
            ]]>
        </description>
        <name>useCurrencySymbol</name>
        <type>java.lang.Boolean</type>
    </attribute>

    <!-- Other attributes. -->
</tag>
```

It has several attributes and it is targeted to convert a string representation to its equivalent `java.math.BigDecimal` value and a `java.math.BigDecimal` to various display formats like currency with or without a currency symbol, percentage, numbers with grouping, number of decimal places in fractional numbers etc.

Naturally, percentage and currency cannot be used together in the example given. So, the following is perfectly valid.

```
<my:convertBigDecimal currency="#{currencyCode}" groupingUsed="true" locale="#{locale}"/>
```

The following would however be invalid and is expected to raise a parse error, if attempted.

```
<my:convertBigDecimal percent="true"
                      currency="#{currencyCode}"
                      useCurrencySymbol="false"
                      groupingUsed="true"
                      locale="#{locale}"/>
```

If for example, the `percent` attribute were to be attempted along with any other attributes associated with currencies like `currency`, `useCurrencySymbol`, then it is supposed that the XML parser should issue a parse error preventing the XML document itself from being parsed.

Would it be possible somehow to force the parser to issue a parse error, if irrelevant attributes were to be attempted to be specified together with the given tag so that several conditional tests in the converter can be omitted and users or application developers using the converter can be warned against using irrelevant attributes in the tag too early?

Comment: The only way I know how to do this is to use XSD/DTD validation... And even then, the mutually exclusive attribute is only possible in XSD 1.1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/763072/xsd-one-of-2-attributes-is-required. So you have to create an XSD and then adapt the runtime-parser and(/or?) configure your IDE to do XSD validation on xhtml files as well. Luckily JSF uses real namespaces unlike the HTML5 data- loosers...

Comment: http://in.relation.to/2009/02/26/its-time-for-facelets-to-start-using-xsd/ Maybe @BalusC could raise this in the spec group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not via XML configuration in `.taglib.xml` file. It's only possible via a real tag handler class registered via `<converter><handler-class>`.

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>bigDecimalConverter</converter-id>
    <handler-class>com.example.BigDecimalConverterHandler</handler-class>
</converter>
```

```
public class BigDecimalConverterHandler extends ConverterHandler {

    public BigDecimalConverterHandler(ConverterConfig config) {
        super(config);

        if (getAttribute("percent") != null && getAttribute("currency") != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hey there, it does not make sense to specify both 'percent' and 'currency' attributes.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What may be the top prioritized possible cause of preventing parse errors from being displayed on the server log leaving the entire page white on the browser whenever the parser fails to parse an XML document? XML parse errors like this are nowhere traceable in my case neither in GlassFish nor in WildFly since the beginning, perhaps, since the time I added templates. [This is still to be fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27795529/1391249). I have no rights to leave this comment here but I have not yet been able to guess the cause, since it works just fine in single page applications.

Comment: Another XML parser/factory shipped in webapp itself?

Comment: I use APIs like Apache POI, jsoup which may use their own parser but I did not add any external XML parser myself to the application.

Comment: those parses won't find these issues. Extend the default jsf parser and before passing on, check against ... a dtd?xsd?